# Behaviour of goto statement

Tags: c, goto

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()  {

    int i;
    goto l;

    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        l:printf("Hi\n");
    }

    return 0;

}
```

The above code gives output three times Hi . I don't have any idea how it happens, please expalin it. If i reducde value of 5 to 3 then only once the Hi printed.

Comment: Don't you notice that `goto l` enters the loop without initializing `i`?

Comment: @iharob-but why it prints 3 three time . If it enters in loop without initialization then what value of i it takes ?

Comment: It is undefined behavior.

Comment: @SumS It's undefined behavior e.g. for me it prints it 5 times

Comment: @Rizier123 exactly, for me it was 4 times.

Comment: @iharob I would say a nice example for undefined behavoir :D (i use: TDM GCC- 4.7.1 64 bit compiler)

Comment: I got "... core dumped" on PowerPC32 compiled with clang.... beat dat :D

Comment: Never ever use goto, i've never find a reason to use it, since all situations can be solved with loops and conditionals, it comes from compilator programming world and it is useless in a high-level program language. It will only gives you archaic and obscure errors like the one you faced.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing the comparison `i < 5` and incrementing `i` in the `for` loop without initializing it first causing undefined behavior (*the value of `i` at that point is a random **garbage** value*)

If you try this instead

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 0;

    goto l;
    for(i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
        l: printf("Hi\n");

    return 0;
}
```

it will have defined behavior and this program will print `Hi` 5 times.

And to see what is going on try

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 4;

    goto l;
    for(i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
        l: printf("Hi\n");

    return 0;
}
```

and `Hi` will be printed only once, becase once you enter the `for` loop, `i == 4`.

So basicaly you are jumping this line

```
for(i = 0 ; i < 5 ; i++)
```

failing to initialize `i` and thus having undefined behavior for the reasons explained above.

Using `goto` is not always bad, but when it's used to control the flow of program, it makes it hard to follow the code and understand what it does, and generally it wont be necessary for that, but it's surely useful in some situations, for example consider this case

```
FILE *file;
int  *x;
int  *y;

file = fopen("/path/to/some/file", "r");
if (file == NULL)
    return IO_ERROR_CODE;

x = malloc(SomeSize * sizeof(int));
if (x == NULL)
{
    fclose(file);
    return MEMORY_EXHAUST_ERROR_CODE;
}

y = malloc(SomeSize * sizeof(int));
if (y == NULL)
{
    free(x);
    fclose(file);
    return MEMORY_EXHAUST_ERROR_CODE;
}

return SUCESS_CODE;
```

so you have to add more and more code at each function exit point, but you could do this instead

```
    FILE *file = NULL;
    int  *x    = NULL;
    int  *y    = NULL;

    file = fopen("/path/to/some/file", "r");
    if (file == NULL)
        return SOME_ERROR_CODE;
    x = malloc(SomeSize * sizeof(int));
    if (x == NULL)
        goto abort;
    y = malloc(SomeSize * sizeof(int));
    if (y == NULL)
        goto abort;

    return SUCCESS_CODE;

abort:
    if (x != NULL)
        free(x);
    if (y != NULL)
        free(y);
    if (file != NULL)
        fclose(file);
    return MEMORY_EXHAUST_ERROR_CODE;
```

of course in your example, there is absolutely no reason to use `goto`.

Comment: you should add that the whole goto is senseless in this case. And people who don't even know that! and are using `goto`... That's the only reason why code gets created, that makes `goto` frowned upon.

Comment: `goto` is really useful in some situations, it prevents violating the DRY principle.

Comment: That's exactly my point of view. my previous comment just tryed to note, that people like OPer producing such goto code make the majority of programmers think, `goto` is the root of all evil.

Comment: @Zaibis sure, but leave as a comment as it is, so you have the credit for mentioning that. I will delete this comment as soon as you read it.

Comment: In my opinion: In you example there is absolutely no reason to use goto. For goto you can use return + a function named "abort". Your example is very difficult to refactor.

Comment: @Wolframm why is my code dificult to refactor? You apparently are not a c programmer from your profile information, and this technique is widely used, i have seen it in the Linux kernel for instance, it sure doesn't make much sense to use `goto` in `C#` i don't even know if there is a `goto` in `C#`.

Comment: If you create a function instead of this `goto`, you can easier put this function in a other file or use it in other production code. When you refactor your code, you will automatically build a function instead of `goto`. For this there is no reason to use `goto`. And the second argument for me is, I cannot see there the function exits at a fast view, because for me `return` with one tab is latest function exit. This is only my opinion :)

Comment: @Wolframm can you give an example of such function?

Comment: @Wolframm your code is way harder to refactor, suppose you have `x, y, z, w, u, v, g` and three more files, you would write a function taking a lot of arguments and each time you add code that requires cleanup, you should fix each call to the function plus the function it self, so that is much harder to refactor. Also, you shouldn;t call it `abort` since there is already a standard `abort` function. In the scope of the function it's not that bad to have an `abort` label, but one should also avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

Your code exhibits [Undefined Behavior](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). This is because when the execution of the program reaches the `goto` statement, the execution of the program jumps inside the body of  the `for` loop, thus skipping the initialization part of the `for` loop. Thus,`i` is uninitialized and it contains a "garbage value".

As a side note: [Using `goto`s are considered to be bad practice](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/46586/goto-still-considered-harmful) as it makes reading/maintaining your code much harder.